# Compiling external dependencies with different compiler flags

Tags: bazel

We are importing external C++ bazel projects with http_archives, but we'd like to compile the external projects with a different set of gcc flags than we use with our own code.

We want to do this because the external projects won't compile with some of the stricter warnings that we want to move to.

Comment: Is the only difference in compiling that you want not to treat warnings as errors in third-party libs?

Comment: I'd really rather not have the warning at all in third-party libraries, but not treating the warning as an error would be more than I have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By far the simplest option, is to create a macro wrapper over cc_library/cc_binary that you use internally e.g.

```py
# my_internal_cc_rules.bzl

_ADDITIONAL_COPTS = [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Werror",
    # etc.
]

def my_cc_library(**kwargs):
    native.cc_library(
        name = kwargs["name"],
        copts = _ADDITIONAL_COPTS + kwargs.get("copts", []),
        **kwargs,
    )

def my_cc_binary(**kwargs):
    native.cc_library(
        name = kwargs["name"],
        copts = _ADDITIONAL_COPTS + kwargs.get("copts", []),
        **kwargs,
    )
```

Then you can use your macro in place of cc_binary/cc_library e.g.

```py
load(":my_internal_cc_rules.bzl", 
    "my_cc_library", 
    "my_cc_binary",
)

my_cc_library(
   name = "foo",
   deps = ["@some_external//:some_cc_library"],
)

my_cc_binary(
   name = "main",
   deps = [":foo"],
   srcs = ["main.cc"],
)
```

Refactoring can be as simple as a string replacement, or you could alternatively use buildozer for refactoring.

A more advanced example of this can be found [google/pigweed](https://github.com/google/pigweed) in the files;

- pw_build/pigweed.bzl
- pw_build/bazel_internal/*.bzl