# How to ignore the errors coming from external library

Tags: bazel

i am using -Wconditional-uninitialized flag and then i am getting some errrors from the library.

external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc:398:12: error: variable 'arena' may be uninitialized when used here [-Werror,-Wconditional-uninitialized] return arena->AllocateAlignedWithCleanup(n, alloc_policy_.get()); ^~~~~ external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/arena.cc:395:21: note: initialize the variable 'arena' to silence this warning SerialArena* arena; ^ = nullptr 1 error generated.

i want to filter out this error since it is coming from the library and i am using Bazel 5.0 and feature : build --features=external_include_paths but still i am seeing the above error from the library.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a c++ application and i am using clang + bazel 5.2 to build the app.

Comment: i have a c++ application and i am using clang + Bazel 5.2 to build the app.
we have a requirement to have "-Wconditional-uninitialized" flag to give a warning if some variable is initialized based on some condition which is absolutely fine.
bazel rc content is like this:

build --features=external_include_paths
build --repo_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++17:-Werror:-Wconditional-uninitialized"

and i am building app with these compiler options and then getting above error from the library.
Since i am using features=external_include_paths i am not expecting this error from the library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiling external dependencies with different compiler flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56401584/compiling-external-dependencies-with-different-compiler-flags)